# Access method from another activity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity called ORDERS, that has a method called OrdersListRefresh(), that refreshes a listview contents. In ORDERDETAILS i want to access the OrderListRefresh() method from the ORDERS. How can i accomplish this, without changing the OrdersListRefresh() method to static?

Thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, create an object of class ORDERS and refer from it. Make OrderListRefresh public.

```
ORDERS  objOrders = new ORDERS();
objOrders.OrderListRefresh()
```